# Fourier Series and Summation

Tags: fourier-analysis, summation, fourier-series

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ can be computed in straight-forward way by computing the Fourier co-efficients of $f(x)=x$ and applying Parseval's identity. Likewise, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4}$ can be computed in the same way using $f(x)=x^2$. Any thoughts on a suitable function for computing $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{n^2}$? If not, how might one approach this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s} - 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)^s}$$

Comment: I should have seen that. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielFischer May I know how to compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)^s}$?

Comment: @JohnZHANG Take out the $\frac{1}{2^s}$ from each term. You get $2^{-s}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer You are right! I was confused by the notation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The series that come out directly from Parseval's identity always have nonnegative terms. So, some reshuffling is necessary to deal with alternating series. Which is what Daniel Fischer's comment delivers:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s} - 2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)^s} \tag{1}$$

As an aside:  rewriting (1) as
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s} = (1-2^{1-s})^{-1}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}  \tag{2}$$
is a way to quickly extend   Riemann's $\zeta$-function into the halfplane $ \operatorname{Re}s>0$. From (2) one sees that $\zeta$ is holomorphic there except for a pole at $s=1$. Unfortunately, it's not as easy to see when the series on the right sums to zero...